# Integrate restaurant Point of Sale with a Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, integration, point-of-sale

I'm developing a restaurant ordering system based on MVC. I have been asked from my clients if it is possible to integrate this application with their POS (Point of Sale).
Basically when someone place an order on on my web app this has to go to their POS system too.
I have done some research on internet but I could not find anything.
Is it something that is possible to do?

Comment: anything is possible. it is a matter of joining the dots, reading the documentation for the POS system you decide to use and integrate it. What have you tried? What systems are you looking at for POS? POS and MVC are separate things altogether. POS is an independent system/unit and it is up to you, the developer, on how to work WITH it to integrate it into your website/solution.

Comment: @massimiliano have u got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible. Contact the company who makes their POS and see what APIs they have, or if they would be willing to develop one for you.